# Empty Git merge removed commits

Tags: git

We have an issue where a developer has accidentally botched a merge and pushed a blank merge commit. See the diagram below:

```
develop  ----A----------------------------------F------------------I
              \                                /                  /
     feature1  B----------------C----------------------G---------H  
                                 \           /
feature2  ------------------------D---------E-----------------------
```

Say that the branch `feature1` was created at point `A` on the `develop` branch. At point `C`, `feature1` was merged into `feature2`. However, this merge was done incorrectly, and commit `D`, the merge commit, was a blank commit that effectively rejected all of the changes from `feature1` (i.e. change `B` and `C` were accidentally rejected).

At point `E`, `feature2` was merged into `develop`. Finally, at point `H`, `feature1` was merged into `develop` in order to bring in changes `G` and `H`.

However, it is expected at point `I` that `develop` will have changes `B` and `C`, as well as `G` and `H`. However, I believe as they were rejected at merge `C -> D`, it does not.

Is there a simple way to fix this scenario, especially baring in mind that in real life many commits and merges have occurred on multiple branches since the bad merge? I'm thinking along the lines of creating a duplicate `develop` branch at point `C`, and using a combination of rebasing and cherry-picking to achieve this. However this is going to be quite laborious to do, so a quick, safe way to rescue the situation would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have two commits labeled `G` in your diagram, but they appear to be different.  Is one supposed to be `F`?

Comment: @torek Yes, you are correct. Fixed.

Comment: I think your plan is pretty much the right way to go.  Note that `git rebase` has `-f` / `--no-ff` specifically to help let you copy commits that `git merge` will consider to be *new* (must-merge) commits, but if they're far enough in the past, you'll face some sort of rework (whether at cherry-pick or merge time).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything quick and/or safe to be done to fix this instance.

To avoid future instances, have you thought of using a rebase-heavy workflow -- only merge when adding to the mainline.

Also, it sounds like maybe you have long-lived feature branches, which could also be the root cause of lots of issues.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you re-run the merge `D` correctly as `D'` and then apply to `I` difference between `D` and `D'` it should fix your issue.

(Note that incorrect `D` merge reverted not only `B` and `C`, but also `develop` history from last commit known to `feature2` to `A`)

Steps should be something like:

```
git checkout -b tmp_fix D~1
git merge C
# now, you have correct D', but you should make it child of D to pick it
git reset --soft D
git commit -m "Fix incorrect merge D"
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick tmp_fix
```